# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, heap-memory

I am facing this issue in running meteor project and it's ruined me all day. Tried all the available solution on the internet but all in vain. Used this command to increase space set TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max_old_space_size=8096"
Please help me in this regard.

```
=> Started proxy.
    => Meteor 1.10.2 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
       Building for web.browser.legacy           -
    <--- Last few GCs --->
    
    [12772:01D8DA18]   341415 ms: Mark-sweep 630.1 (720.1) -> 629.9 (723.1) MB, 786.3 / 0.1 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
    [12772:01D8DA18]   342385 ms: Mark-sweep 629.9 (723.1) -> 629.9 (699.6) MB, 970.5 / 0.1 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
    [12772:01D8DA18]   343313 ms: Mark-sweep 629.9 (699.6) -> 629.9 (692.1) MB, 928.1 / 0.1 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
    
    
    <--- JS stacktrace --->
    
    ==== JS stack trace =========================================
    
    Security context: 03E96201 <JSObject>
        1: fromString(aka fromString) [buffer.js:314] [bytecode=0575EE49 offset=164](this=03C8417D <undefined>,string=180D0DC9 <Very long string[34088076]>,encoding=03E9EFFD <String[4]: utf8>)
        2: from [buffer.js:177] [bytecode=0575EAF9 offset=11](this=043AB369 <JSFunction Buffer (sfi = 03EC8CDD)>,value=180D0DC9 <Very long string[34088076]>,encodingOrOffset=03E9EFFD <String[4]: utf8>,length=03C8417D <u...
    
    FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
     1: node_module_register
     2: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString
     3: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint
```

Comment: Can you narrow down your server startup to a certain piece of code that causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

The command line option you are trying to make use of: [--max-old-space-size](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_old_space_size_size_in_megabytes) might not be picked up because you assigned it to the `TOOL_NODE_FLAGS` environment variable when you should really be assigning it to `NODE_OPTIONS`(see reference for that claim in Node docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options)). I read a fair amount online saying `TOOL_NODE_FLAGS` won't be picked up by some spawned Node processes.

I ran into a similiar build error at some point for one of my Meteor apps and fixed it by applying the flag as seen below:

[image]